# Pass Data from controller to view is not responding. Is there something wrong in the code?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

The website I am coding is working fine except for the remove from cart option. I don't get any error in the code but when I click the link for remove from cart the code does nothing. It seems as if the page just refreshes. I am coding the system in C#.net MVC 4. Please can someone help me.

This is part of the ShoppingCartController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
{
    // Remove the item from the cart
    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

    // Get the name of the album to display confirmation
    string albumName = storeDB.Carts
            .Single(item => item.RecordId == id).Album.Title;

    // Remove from cart
    int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

    // Display the confirmation message
    var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
    {
        Message = Server.HtmlEncode(albumName) +
                " has been removed from your shopping cart.",
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                ItemCount = itemCount,
                DeleteId = id
    };

    return Json(results);
}
```

This is part of the ShoppingCart model.

```
public int RemoveFromCart(int id)
{
    // Get the cart
    var cartItem = storeDB.Carts.Single(
    cart => cart.CartId == ShoppingCartId
        && cart.RecordId == id);

    int itemCount = 0;

    if (cartItem != null)
    {
        if (cartItem.Count > 1)
        {
            cartItem.Count--;
            itemCount = cartItem.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            storeDB.Carts.Remove(cartItem);
        }

        // Save changes
        storeDB.SaveChanges();
    }

    return itemCount;
}
```

Lastly this is the ShoppingCart/Index view.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
{
    <tr id="row-@item.RecordId">
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Album.Title, "Details", "Shop", new { id = item.AlbumId }, null)
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Album.Price
        </td>
        <td id="item-count-@item.RecordId">
            @item.Count
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="RemoveFromCart" data-id="(@item.RecordId == id).Album.Title">Remove from cart</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Yes I have and it does not link to the RemoveFromCart in the ShoppingCartController.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've got some javascript somewhere that is handling the `onclick` of your "Remove from cart" link or adding an `href` to it, your current `href` of `"#"` will 'seem to refresh the page' exactly as you've described.  Consider changing that anchor tag to an `ActionLink` like your Details link but that points to your `RemoveFromCart` action method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Html.ActionLink` instead of `a` tag, just like you do for Shop/Details action. Example (assuming that your `RemoveFromCart` action is in `ShopController` and you want to delete an item with id = item.AlbumId):

```
@Html.ActionLink(
     "Remove from cart", 
     "RemoveFromCart", 
     "Shop", 
     new { id = item.AlbumId }, 
     new { @class = "RemoveFromCart"})
```

This way full page refresh will be performed and you will need to return View from your action. To make only partial refresh you will need to use `Ajax.ActionLink` helper.

Comment: I have done as you suggested and added the following code.

                    @Html.ActionLink("Remove from cart", 
     "CartSummary", 
     "ShoppingCart", 
     new { id = item.AlbumId}, 
     new { @class = "RemoveFromCart"})

However I get an error when I click remove from cart saying "The action 'CartSummary' is accessible only by a child request."

Comment: Do you have [ChildActionOnly] attribute on your CartSummary action? Also please note that Html.ActionLink sends only get requests.

Comment: This is what the CartSummary action has the following code: 
@Html.ActionLink("Cart (" + ViewData["CartCount"] + ")",
    "Index",
    "ShoppingCart",
    new { id = "cart-status" })

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, please refer to [this ActionLink description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: Sorry I gave you the code for the CartSummary View there. Yes the cart summary does have a [ChildActionOnly] attribute.